# Crash during boot when linux-modules-extra is installed

Tags: crash

Since 2021, I have only used kernel version 5.4 (20.04LTS) because any other will crash at boot.

[My log is here when I try to boot with another version](https://pastebin.com/jCFWi12d) (here 5.15 while `linux-modules-extra` is installed)

I can, however, boot with any other kernel version while `linux-modules-extra` is not installed.

But if  `linux-modules-extra` is not installed, I won't have ethernet, sound, etc., working.

If someone may have a clue,

The solution is using `pci=noacpi`

Comment: @guiverc If I'm not mistaken, the crash log is from when they tried to boot from another kernel while linux-modules-extra is installed, because 5.4 (or 5.04 or whatever it is) is the only kernel that will boot when that package (linux-modules-extra) is installed.

Comment: @guiverc ChatGPT analyzed my log ang gave me a solution ! Adding pci=noacpi to grub!